# Append different value to same name key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want an output like this:

```
 [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]
```

But I am getting this output:

```
  [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}]
```

I tried the below code:

```
  l = []
  d = {}
  for i in range(0,4):
     d['a'] = i
     print("dictinary ",d)
     print("list before appending ",l)
     l.append(d)
     print("list after appending ",l)
  print(l)
```

I am getting the below output after applying print statements(for debugging)

```
    dictinary  {'a': 0}
    list before appending  []
    list after appending  [{'a': 0}]
    dictinary  {'a': 1}
    list before appending  [{'a': 1}]
    list after appending  [{'a': 1}, {'a': 1}]
    dictinary  {'a': 2}
    list before appending  [{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]
    list after appending  [{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]
    dictinary  {'a': 3}
    list before appending  [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}]
    list after appending  [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}]
    [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3}]
```

I cannot understand one thing: **Why my list value is getting changed on changing dictionary value ?** **i.e. On executing line no 4 in code, the value of the list is automatically getting changed(See line no 5 of output).** Please suggest something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create new `dictionary` In `for-loop`. in Your code you have one `dictionary` with one `address` when changing one of them all changing.
Try this:

```
l = []
for i in range(0,4):
    d = {}
    d['a'] = i
    print("dictinary ",d)
    print("list before appending ",l)
    l.append(d)
    print("list after appending ",l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
dictinary  {'a': 0}
list before appending  []
list after appending  [{'a': 0}]
dictinary  {'a': 1}
list before appending  [{'a': 0}]
list after appending  [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}]
dictinary  {'a': 2}
list before appending  [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}]
list after appending  [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
dictinary  {'a': 3}
list before appending  [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
list after appending  [{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]
[{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]
```